# pyqt5 GUI freezing even when QThread is used

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm trying to make a desktop application and want to implement threading so app does not freeze while running large tasks.
but when Iam trying to use Qthread application is running but becomes unresponsive.
below added code is a rough of my main code, I've even attached the qt designers generated code for the dialog.

> rough code

```
import time
from progress import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, QTimer, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Progress_dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Progress_dialog, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)

        self.btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('click me', self)
        self.btn_1.move(150,0)
        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.startworker_1)

        self.bar = self.ui.progressBar

    def startworker_1(self):
        self.thred = QThread()
        self.thred.start()
        self.thred.started.connect(self.progress_bar)
    
    def progress_bar(self):
        import time
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        for cnt in range(1,101):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.bar.setValue(cnt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Progress_dialog()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> gui script

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 425)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 351))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 371, 21))
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.progressBar.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

anyone having QT experience can answer

Comment: You cannot modify a widget directly from a worker thread - your call to `self.bar.setValue(cnt)` in the `progress_bar` method will not work because it does exactly that. What you need to do instead is to use the Signals and Slots mechanisms provided by Qt in order to transfer data betweeen the worker thread and the GUI thread. Please read [this tutorial](https://www.mfitzp.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/) in order to understand how to do that.

Comment: Note that the code shown doesn't appear to actually use the new thread created by the `QThread` instance.  I suspect `Progress_dialog::progress_bar` is being run on (and therefore blocking) the GUI thread.  Does the GUI freeze for approx 10 seconds.

Comment: no gui only freezes when i use time.sleep() if run it without time.sleep() then the progress bar works flawlessly

Comment: Sounds like the `progress bar` method is running on the GUI thread then, as @G.M. pointed out. Using `time.sleep()` on the GUI thread is a bad idea, because it also makes the GUI unresponsive - the GUI cannot process any events (like updating the progress bar) because it spends 99% of the time sleeping.